# I just started using Android Studio and everything I try and add becomes really small and moves to the top left corner

Tags: android-studio

I just started using Android Studio and everything I try and add on the design page becomes really small and moves to the top left corner. I used the code page to try and add a text line but I got the same thing. Could you please please please help me with this? [screen shot with the lines of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0448.png)
[screen shot with the design page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CAST.png)

Comment: [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2745495). Instead, add and **[format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** your code into the post itself as **text**.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're over-constraining the entries. The constraints for the first TextView will squash it to 0 size (top to top of parent, and bottom to top of parent means a height of 0).

Try something like this, like your second option but without the bias arguments (which are likely what was pushing it to the top left corner). This should be horizontally centered and at the top of the screen. The default bias is 0.5, so centered between constraints.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myHello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

If you want it left aligned instead of centered, simply remove the "right to right of" constraint.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried but I still get the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried running the app to see what it looks like there (rather than just looking at the Android Studio preview)? Sometimes the preview is wrong.

Comment: Yes. All I got was a black screen and some white text saying "android", but this is not what my text says.

Comment: You are describing the android boot screen, that doesn't sound like the emulator even started or launched your app.